# Flutter and Json Retrieve a Title where value is

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have a Json array that is from wordpress. It retrives posts.
Each post has a serie of custom_options.

here an example:

```
{
  "options":{
    "wpcf-fields-select-option-f1d645c9017cce89714ede343df0cc73-1":{
      "title":"-Select-",
      "value":""
    },
    "wpcf-fields-select-option-3e64c784ce30a384e5167d1d6c1feb4e-1":{
      "title":"1\/5",
      "value":"S14"
    },
    "wpcf-fields-select-option-48334e061de93e6c47cc42c0fb5cd180-1":{
      "title":"1\/8",
      "value":"S1"
    },
    "wpcf-fields-select-option-a061ee2d2d302c5f42b2c93f9e811cdc-1":{
      "title":"1\/12",
      "value":"S2"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to call a function that will return the title of a given value.

Already tried using

```
// infoList is the json object
// resultVal is the value I am searching for
String getarrayinfos (infoList, resultVal) {
    var result;
    Map thisList = infoList;

    for(var eachArr in thisList.keys){
      if(thisList[eachArr]["value"] == resultVal){
        result = thisList[eachArr]["title"];
      }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

and printing it as the child of a container

```
// options is the json Object
// S7 is the value I am searching for 
child: Text(getarrayinfos(options, "S7")),
```

but it prints the following error

```
flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the value of  `options`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code (apart from being overly complex), so most likely the arguments are not what you expect them to be. The error message suggests that something is a `List`, rather than the `Map` you expect. It would also be helpful to see the stack trace associated with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking in `infoList.keys` look into `infoList.values`:

```
String getArrayInfo(Map theMap, String searchText) {
  for (var val in theMap['options'].values) {
    if (val['value'] == searchText) return (val['title']);
  }
  return 'not found';
}

void main() {
  Map myMap = {
    "options": {
      "wpcf-fields-select-option-f1d645c9017cce89714ede343df0cc73-1": {
        "title": "-Select-",
        "value": ""
      },
      "wpcf-fields-select-option-3e64c784ce30a384e5167d1d6c1feb4e-1": {
        "title": "1\/5",
        "value": "S14"
      },
      "wpcf-fields-select-option-48334e061de93e6c47cc42c0fb5cd180-1": {
        "title": "1\/8",
        "value": "S1"
      },
      "wpcf-fields-select-option-a061ee2d2d302c5f42b2c93f9e811cdc-1": {
        "title": "1\/12",
        "value": "S2"
      }
    }
  };

  print(getArrayInfo(myMap, "S14"));
}
```

Comment: I/flutter ( 5093): Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: After a few test I realized that it is a String...

    String getArrayInfos (Map infoList, resultVal) {
        var something;
        for(var eachArr in infoList.values){
            something = json.encode(eachArr);
            print(something);
        }
        return something;
    }

Comment: Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: I think I understand why is not working.

On the for cycle when I try to print eachArr['title'] it works until one of the objects does not have the same format {title: mytitle, value: my value}

the JSON is 

    {
    wpcf-fields-select-option-f1d645c9017cce89714ede343df0cc73-1: {title: - Select -, value: }, 
    default: wpcf-fields-select-option-f1d645c9017cce89714ede343df0cc73-1, 
    wpcf-fields-select-option-3e64c784ce30a384e5167d1d6c1feb4e-1: {title: 1/5, value: S14}, 

    }

it's the default record that is stopping the process...

How do I fix this?

Comment: add another condition in if `val['value'] is !String`